# Creating a bootable iso image with Imgburn

Tags: image, disk

I am trying to create a bootable iso image so that I can burn it onto a disk and boot from it. I am using Imgburn. I clicked on the advanced tab then on make image bootable. Further down it says to select an image (.bin). I have two .bin files; John Fine's bootf02 bootsector and my kernel.bin file. Which one do I enter there? What do I do with the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to say if you want to do a floppy drive emulation or a hard disk emulation.

The file you enter must be the image of the floppy disk or the hard disk.

This means: The file must contain the boot sector (bootf02) in the first 512 bytes and the kernel.bin data somewhere else.

Where exactly the kernel.bin file is located within the image file depends on the boot sector.

Depending on the boot sector it may also be impossible to create a bootable CD-ROM image.

Comment: So I have to create aother file containing both the kernel and bootsector and that is the file I enter there?